# Need some formula assistance in for salary preparation using excel

Tags: excel

I need some assistance in order to work it out for salary purpose
 last two digits of decimal points as follws

1. if 00 to 12, then 00
2. if 13 to 37, then round up to 25
3. if 38 to 62, then round up to 50
4. if 63 to 87, then round up to 75
5. if 88 or more , then round up to 100

examples:

```
By Apllying the above principles

     if the amount is  79.109 have to change it to  79.100  
     if the amount is 132.528 have to change it to 132.525
     if the amount is 258.739 have to change it to 258.750
     if the amount is 452.264 have to change it to 452.275
```

And also if the amount is 124.998 have to change it to 125.000

Comment: You will need to provide more information. For example are all your numbers measured to 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

With data in A1 try this formula in B1 to round as required

`=ROUND(A1*4,1)/4`

Edit: MROUND is another possibility, i.e.

`=MROUND(A1,0.025)`

....but MROUND is only a native excel function in Excel 2007 and later (in Analysis ToolPak in earlier versions)